# Using React-Query for repeat search behaviour

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I'm trying to do the following with React-Query :

I have a modal dialog which contains a search input field (with a search button next to it) and a bunch of other form fields. The goal is to enable the user to enter an id and upon clicking the search button a 'search' endpoint is called and if a corresponding entity is found, the other form fields are hydrated using this entity.

I can't think of a 'natural feeling' way of doing this with React-Query.

The best I can come up with is as follows :

```
const [searchId, setSearchId] = useState()
const getEntity = useGetEntity({ id: searchId }); // just a useQuery wrapping hook which uses enabled: !!id

useEffect(() => {
  const found = getEntity.data
  if (found) {
    form.setFieldsValue(_.pick(found, ['name', 'address', 'country'])) // hydrate the form - I'm using antd here
    setSearchId(null); 
    // otherwise the user wouldn't be able to repeat the search with the same id
  }
}, [getEntity .data])
```

where useGetEntity :

```
export const useGetEntity = ({ id }) => {
  return useQuery({
    queryKey: ['searchedEntity', id],
    queryFn: () => fetchEntity(id), // axios call
    enabled: !!id
  })
}
```

...where clicking the search button triggers `setSearchId(id)`

But this feels off somehow. Is there a better approach ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to approach this is to split the Search and the Form into two different components, and pass the data as a prop to the Search form, where it can be used as initial state for the local state. The `useGetEntity` hook looks perfect.

```
const [searchId, setSearchId] = useState()
const getEntity = useGetEntity({ id: searchId });

if (getEntity.data) {
  return <MyForm initialData={getEntity.data} />
}

// loading and error handling for the query goes her
```

> // otherwise the user wouldn't be able to repeat the search with the same id

if that is a requirement, the best way to do it is to check for equality of the `searchId`, and then trigger `refetch()` returned from `useQuery` instead of setting the id, something like:

```
<button onClick={() => {
  (id === searchId) ? refetch() : setSearchId(id)
}}>Search</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`React-Query` is often used for advance http calls. you can simply fetch your data with `axios` and save the data to your state and also reference your field values to your state so that any state change leads to re-rendering and hydrating your form fields.

```js
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
  name: null,
  address: null,
  country: null
})
//////////

//call this for search
function getApiData(){
let data = await axios.get('URL');
setFormData({
  name:data.name,
  address:data.address,
  country:data.country
  })
}
```

Also implementing **loading indicator** is a good UX experience while your app is fetching data.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I'm using AntD and (as far as I understand) their Form components don't permit passing form state as a prop (apart from the initial values). I therefore have to programmatically set it upon the search. I take the point that I could bypass ReactQuery completely for this use case however I was wondering if there's a 'standard' RQ pattern used in such situations...